# Who said "Spinor is a square root of a vector"?

Tags: resource-recommendations, terminology, spinors, history

I'm trying to find out who said that "spinor is a square root of a vector". According to a source (Yu. B. Rumer, A. I. Fet, Group theory and quantized fields, Nauka, 1977 (in Russian) ), it was van der Waerden, but there is no reference there, ChatGPT says this phrase is often attributed to Pauli.

I would very much appreciate a reference.

Comment: It might be prudent to indicate your source so that those who might have an idea know your source also. Also, please don't use AI/LLM as a basis for Q&A on this size (cf. [this policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281/25301)).

Comment: @KyleKanos : Thank you. PLease see my EDIT.

Comment: ChatGPT notoriously gives false references and citations. You'd get better information from a random stranger on the street.

Comment: This seems more suitable for HSM SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- J.A.Wheeler, "Neutrinos, Gravitation and Geometry" in *Geometrodynamics* (1962),
  p. 90 has a small section entitled "II.4 - Spinor as square root of a vector?

  - one reference, but certainly not the earliest

Possibly useful:

- A. Trautman
  "Clifford and the 'square root' ideas" (1991)
  http://trautman.fuw.edu.pl/publications/Papers-in-pdf/87.pdf

> This review article begins with a short history of the notions associated with spinors; it describes several distinct ‘square root’ ideas occurring in
> connection with Clifford algebras, spin groups and pure spinors. Applications
> of pure spinors to geometry and physics are briefly presented. An appendix
> contains a simple derivation of the Vahlen-Ahlfors, fractional-linear form of
> Mobius transformations.